# How can I find elements that have similar absolute positioning?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the following code there are three images that are on the same position. The position of images are retrieved from a database and they vary every time the page is refreshed.

How can I find and select the elements that have similar absolute positioning with jQuery/JavaScript? I would like to change the position of images that overlap.

```
<img style="position:absolute; top:249.93px; left:291.056px;">
<img style="position:absolute; top:123.44px; left:291.056px;">
<img style="position:absolute; top:249.93px; left:291.056px;">
<img style="position:absolute; top:152.281px; left:582.871px;">
<img style="position:absolute; top:151.803px; left:365.156px;">
<img style="position:absolute; top:249.93px; left:291.056px;">
```

Comment: Two suggestions. (1) try searching for "javascript collision detection", (2) maybe [jQuery masonry plugin](http://masonry.desandro.com) would do the job.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you just want to change the posistion of images that overlap, 
comparing the top and left between two images is enough.
Example:

```
var imglist = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
if (imglist.length > 1) {
    var distance = 1.5; // change the value 
    for (var i = 0; i < imglist.length; i++) {
        for (var j = i + 1; j < imglist.length; j++) {
            var t1 = imglist[i].style.top.replace('px', '');
            var l1 = imglist[i].style.left.replace('px', '');
            var t2 = imglist[j].style.top.replace('px', '');
            var l2 = imglist[j].style.left.replace('px', '');
            if (Math.abs(t1 - t2) <= distance && Math.abs(l1 - l2) <= distance) {
                // imglist[i] && imglist[j] have similar or the same position
                // TODO what you want
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically, I created 2 loops, 1 will go over all the elements and the second is to go over all the other elements so we can compare positions.
Use this code:

```
var arr = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
for(i=0; i<arr.length; i++) {
    console.log(arr[i]);
    for(j=0; j<arr.length-1; j++) {
         if((arr[i].offsetTop == arr[j].offsetTop) && (arr[i].offsetLeft == arr[j].offsetLeft)) { 
            alert('top: ' + arr[i].offsetTop + ' left: ' + arr[j].offsetLeft);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Why not explain your answer, rather than just providing code?

Comment: Yeah, I noticed that after I posted my code, sheesh :P

Comment: I re-read my comment... sorry about that. I just thought it'd be helpful to explain what you've provided. Then noobs like me can learn a thing or two from your approach.

Comment: No worries, you were right, I should have provided an explanation from the beginning.

Answer (score 1):

First you can assign a class to all your elements you want to query ( say 'elementClass')

```
<img class="elementClass" style="position:absolute; top:249.93px; left:291.056px;">
<img class="elementClass" style="position:absolute; top:123.44px; left:291.056px;">
<img class="elementClass" style="position:absolute; top:249.93px; left:291.056px;">
<img class="elementClass" style="position:absolute; top:152.281px; left:582.871px;">
<img class="elementClass" style="position:absolute; top:151.803px; left:365.156px;">
<img class="elementClass" style="position:absolute; top:249.93px; left:291.056px;">
```

then all the elements by either `document.getElementsByClass('elementClass')` or `$('.elementClass')`

Then iterate the collection

```
var results = [];
var elements = document.getElementsByClass('elementClass')
for(int i =0 ; i< elements.length;i++)
{
   var eleResult = {};
   eleResult.id = elements[i].id;
   eleResult.position = elements[i].position();
   results.push(eleResult);
}
```

Then you can group the results on **position** attribute having similar position values(You can write your util method or if want can use linq.js). Advantage of grouping is that you can check group count and do more logic if you want.

Hope it helps!